Shiny IBleManager being null .NET MAUI
I am trying to use Shiny.NET in my maui project for bluetooth, for that I have installed Shiny.BluetoothLE and Shiny.Hosting.Maui dependencies as mentioned on the docs page.
However I am getting null BleManager even after using dependency injection to use it.
MauiProgram.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Shiny;
using Shiny.BluetoothLE;

namespace shinyTest
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseShiny()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .Services.AddSingleton<IBleManager, BleManager>();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}

MainPage.xaml.cs
using Shiny.BluetoothLE;

namespace shinyTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;
        private IBleManager bleManager;
        public MainPage(IBleManager bleManager)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.bleManager = bleManager;
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new BluePage(bleManager)); 
        }
    }

}

BluePage.xaml.cs
using Shiny;
using Shiny.BluetoothLE;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace shinyTest;

public partial class BluePage : ContentPage
{
    private IBleManager _bleManager;
    public BluePage(IBleManager bleManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _bleManager = bleManager;   
    }
    private async void scan_btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_bleManager==null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Null bleManager", "BLE is NULL", "OK");
            return;
        }
        IEnumerable<IPeripheral> connected_devices; 

        try
        {
            connected_devices = _bleManager.GetConnectedPeripherals();

            await DisplayAlert("Connected Devices", $"{connected_devices}", "Ok");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "ok");
        }
    }
}

on clicking the button the alert of Null BleManager is shown. And on removing this 'if' check it is providing the exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
Help appreciated!

That's not a Shiny BLE problem, that looks like a dependency injection issue to me. Are you using Shell? Automatic dependency resolution only works when you use Shell. How, where and when is your MainPage instantiated? Where do you expect the IBleManager instance to come from?

@Julian Yes I am using Shell.

And how is the MainPage instantiated?

@Julian
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>(); 
I have add this to MauiProgram.cs
Really appreciate your effort!
Please correct if I am wrong!
Thanks!

@Julian I am actually new to .NET MAUI , hence I am confused!

You may need the following code:
builder.Services.AddBluetoothLE();

I don't know if that's the same as the AddSingleton call you have, but that's what is explained in the docs here:
https://shinylib.net/client/ble/
See the MauiProgram.cs tab.
